# Why is this program not entering my ElseIf statement -- System.DBNull

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement, dbnull

I imported an Excel file into an ASP.NET DataTable.  Some of the values are blank, specifically at indexes 2 and 3, and I would like to set those blank fields to `0`.

When debugging, the values for `row.item(2)` and `row.item(3)` are both `System.DBNull`.  Interestingly enough, the program enters the `If` statement and sets `row.item(2)` value to 0, but it never enters the `ElseIf` statement. What is going on?  Here's my code:

```
If row.Item(2) Is Nothing OrElse row.Item(2).ToString = "" OrElse IsDBNull(row.Item(2)) Then
    dt.Rows.Item(i).SetField(2, 0)

ElseIf row.Item(3) Is Nothing OrElse row.Item(3).ToString = "" OrElse IsDBNull(row.Item(3)) Then
    dt.Rows.Item(i).SetField(3, 0)
End If
```

EDIT:

Per Tim's suggestion, I revised my code as follows:

```
If Not row.Field(Of Int32?)(2).HasValue Then
    dt.Rows.Item(i).SetField(2, 0)
End If

If Not row.Field(Of Int32?)(3).HasValue Then
    dt.Rows.Item(i).SetField(3, 0)
End If
```

However, this is throwing an error--`Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types`

When debugging, in the first loop:

`row.Item(2) = 17`

`row.Item(3) = 1`

Theoretically, it should skip this iteration and proceed to the next.  However, my program immediately catches the exception with the above error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your `if` is executing, your `else if` will not execute.

If you want your `else if` logic to execute even if your `if` executes, just make it it's own `if` block:

```
If row.Item(2) Is Nothing OrElse row.Item(2).ToString = "" OrElse IsDBNull(row.Item(2)) Then
    dt.Rows.Item(i).SetField(2, 0)
End If

If row.Item(3) Is Nothing OrElse row.Item(3).ToString = "" OrElse IsDBNull(row.Item(3)) Then
    dt.Rows.Item(i).SetField(3, 0)
End If
```

Comment: Wow. That's like programming 101 and I failed at it.  Thanks!

Comment: Side-note: It's better to use the strongly typed `Field`-extension method which also supports nullable types. For example: `If Not row.Field(Of Int32?)(2).HasValue row.SetField(2, 2) End If`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, the strongly typed `Field` extension is not working for me.  See the main post edit for details.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Just finished typing it.

Comment: @user1496816: will hve a look tomorrow, don't have time now :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide sample data so we just have to guess.  But my guess is that you want two If statements.. not an ElseIf.  ElseIf will only evaluate if the If statement returns false.